# Input premium emoji telethon

Tags: python, emoji, telethon

I have a telegram bot into which the user enters text for sending. The mailing is carried out by the telethon client. The problem is that the client cannot send premium emoji.

I know that in order to send a premium Emoji, the text must be in the format: `[](emoji/5388790256772331442)` where the numbers are the document_id of the Emoji.

**The question is how to get it?**
Simply put, how can I make it so that I immediately write down `[](emoji/5388790256772331442)` instead of '' when receiving an Emoji?

I wrote code to get the document_id of an Emoji and even the object of this Emoji, but to get it the text must already be in the format `[](emoji/5388790256772331442)`, although Python itself perceives premium Emoji as ''.

```
me = await client.get_me()
access_hash = me.access_hash

prem_emoji = await client(functions.messages.SearchCustomEmojiRequest(
    emoticon=text, # my text with premium emoji
    hash=access_hash
))
emoji_ids = prem_emoji.document_id # List with premium emoji ids
    
emojies = await client(functions.messages.GetCustomEmojiDocumentsRequest(
    document_id=emoji_ids
))
logging.info(emojies) # return Emoji Object
```

Comment: Whose number is that?  It has nothing to do with the emoji.  Is that a Telethon creation?

Comment: this is  premium emoji id in telegram api

Answer (score 1):

I dug into the documentation and found the answer for myself.
All messages are Message objects, they in turn have “entities”, printed, found MessageEntities of type custom_emoji_id where the Emoji id is located.

```
entities = []
for entity in message.entities:
    if entity.type == 'custom_emoji':
        custom_emoji_id = entity.custom_emoji_id
        entities.append(custom_emoji_id)
entities = ", ".join(entities)
```

Next, simply look for emoji in the text using the pattern and replace them with `[{emoji}](emoji/entities[i])` and the telethon client will write you a premium emoji